# How to combine two dataframes and put 0 and 1 if there are matches between columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Pandas:

| name | number |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 102 |
| apple | 104 |
| banana | 103 |
| banana | 105 |

and the other one (that's the real and true dataset of
comparison)

| name | number |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 102 |
| banana | 105 |

I want to create another column to the first dataframe (called match) and put 0 if the number from first dataframe IS NOT in the second (and real) dataframe and 1 if it is. So basically, a left join, but to add a new column for seeing if the number is present in the other dataset.

The output should be:

| name | number | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 102 | 1 |
| apple | 104 | 0 |
| banana | 103 | 0 |
| banana | 105 | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.isin()` to check if the element appears in another series and `.astype()` to convert True/False into 1/0:

```
df1['match'] = df1['number'].isin(df2['number']).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
      name  number  match
0    apple     102      1
1    apple     104      0
2   banana     103      0
3   banana     105      1
```

**EDIT:**

If not only number should be matched, but name as well, you can use `.isin()` with `.index`:

```
df1['match'] = (df1.set_index(['name', 'number']).index
                   .isin(df2.set_index(['name', 'number']).index)
                   .astype(int)
               )
```

Comment: this won't work per group, if there was a banana/104 the output would likely be incorrect

Comment: Thanks. It is not specified in the question - only number is mentioned there, but I edited my answer and added solution for the case you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with an assigned column that you [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) afterwards:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(match=1), how='left').fillna({'match': 0}, downcast='infer')
```

Another idea would be to use the `indicator` parameter:

```
(df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='match')
    .assign(match=lambda d: d['match'].eq('both').astype(int))
 )
```

output:

```
     name  number  match
0   apple     102      1
1   apple     104      0
2  banana     103      0
3  banana     105      1
```

Comment: First time I see the "downcast='infer'" paramater, just read the documentation but wasn't really helpful. I also tried your answer without using it and it worked too. So why using it here? Any reason am I missing? Thank you @mozway

Comment: this is just to convert to integer if all values are float without decimal, if you don't mind having `1.0` in place of `1` you can leave it out ;)

Comment: How to match the "name" and "number" column as well? What happens when we have, for example multiple columns for first dataframe and only 2 columns for dataframe 2?

Comment: @stephsmith what do you mean? This is already using name and number (actually all columns) to perform the match

Comment: I see, then use `on=['name', 'column']` as parameter for `merge`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'name'] in df_2.name.values and df.loc[i, 'number'] in df_2.number.values:
       df.loc[i, 'match'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'match'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['match'] = (df1.merge(df2, on='name')
                .eval('number_x==number_y')
                .astype(int)
               )
df1
```

Output:

```
     name  number  match
0   apple     102      1
1   apple     104      0
2  banana     103      0
3  banana     105      1
```